# What is the fastest way of loading models in OpenGL ES Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to create a game in android with java not ndk.I want to learn how can we load models in screen and what is the fastest way of it?Which way the professionals use for load models?

I have seen some libraries but i heard that they are very slow.

Comment: What do you mean by 'loading models'? From disk to memory, or from memory to GPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your have GPU's support,you could try VBO tech, that load vertexes into GPU's momory.

Comment: Okey.If there is a source about this,can you share it?

Comment: what's your email, I send it to you.Haha,I'm not good at it,please just look at it and go.If you enjoy it,i past some line here then.

Comment: I didn't understand what you say :D

Comment: -_-||| Give me your email address，I'll send you a example.